# Is Firestore concurrent connections is limited to 1M?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Previous I read in documentation that Firestore can handle any number of  concurrent connections once moved from beta. But now I read in documentation that realtime updates is limited to 1M concurrent connections per database.

Please explain me clearly!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, he concurrent connection connections limit is 1M, as specified here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Comment: That page specifies the "Maximum concurrent connections for mobile/web clients per database" as 1 million.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But when in beta, that page specifies 1M connection limit will be removed once moved from beta. But now why there is a limit?

Comment: I see nothing on that page that the limit of 1M concurrent connections only applies to the beta period. If it said that before, it was removed since, and the current statement seems to apply to the current product.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write 1M, not 10M. I've edited my answer. As Frank mentioned, I don't see anything about the beta period.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if it is limited to 1M, then is there anyway to create multiple databases like in Firebase Realtime Database to handle more traffic.